# messaging failed-service-worker-registration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

An error occurred while retrieving the token.  `FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope`

http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scopewith script http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. messaging/failed-service-worker registration.
at register defaults registerDefaultSw.ts:43:1 at async updateSwReg updateSwReg.ts:28:1
at async getToken$1 getToken.ts:43:1
at async fetchToken firebase.js:25:1`

Due to the homepage/basename of the react js project, I am getting an error when trying to reach the public folder firebase-messaging-sw.js file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to changing default path of service worker in getToken

sth like this :

```
export const askForNotification = async () => {
  const tempMessaging = await messaging();

  if (tempMessaging) {
    const newSw = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(
      '/homepage/basename/firebase-messaging-sw.js'
    );

    return getNotificationPermission(
      async () => await getToken(tempMessaging, { vapidKey, serviceWorkerRegistration:newSw })
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: where should be this function?

Comment: anywhere, but call it in the root of react tree  like index.jsx or app.jsx @FauricioValencia